# Codeceptjs Error - Please make sure Selenium Server (ChromeDriver or PhantomJS) is running and accessible

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation, codeceptjs

```
CodeceptJS v3.0.5
Using test root "/Users/bhupendrarautela/extram"

login --
  ✖ "before all" hook: codeceptjs.beforeSuite for "test something" in 17ms
Error: Can't connect to WebDriver.
Error: Failed to create session.
Unable to connect to "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", make sure browser driver is running on 
that address.
If you use services like chromedriver see initialiseServices logs above or in wdio.log file 
as the service might had problems to start the driver.

Please make sure Selenium Server (ChromeDriver or PhantomJS) is running and accessible

-- FAILURES:

  1) login
       "before all" hook: codeceptjs.beforeSuite for "test something":
     Can't connect to WebDriver.
Error: Failed to create session.
Unable to connect to "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", make sure browser driver is running on 
that address.
If you use services like chromedriver see initialiseServices logs above or in wdio.log file 
as the service might had problems to start the driver.

Please make sure Selenium Server (ChromeDriver or PhantomJS) is running and accessible
  Error: Failed to create session.
  Unable to connect to "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", make sure browser driver is running 
on that address.
  If you use services like chromedriver see initialiseServices logs above or in wdio.log file as the service might had problems to start the driver.




  FAIL  | 0 passed, 1 failed   // 19ms
Run with --verbose flag to see complete NodeJS stacktrace
```

Please help me with how to make sure Selenium Server (ChromeDriver or PhantomJS) is running and accessible.

Comment: I have a similar issue. Have you got the solution?